# Almost completed decimal to any base conversion function, cannot figure out how to implement hexidecimal conversion

Tags: c

I am almost done with the last method of my project, but I just can not seem to figure out how to convert from decimal to hexidecimal. My code is below

```
int main() {
  printf("Binary to decimal: %s\n", decToBase(2, 25));
  printf("Octal to decimal: %s\n", decToBase(8, 111));
  printf("Hexidecimal to decimal: %s\n", decToBase(16, 248));
}

char* decToBase(int base, int dec) {
  char* temp = (char*)malloc(32*sizeof(char));
  char* ret = (char*)malloc(32*sizeof(char));

  int i = 0;
  while(dec > 0) {
    temp[i] = (dec % base);

    if(temp[i] < 58)
      temp[i] += '0';
    else
      temp[i] += 'a';

    dec = dec / base;
    i++;
  }

  int end = strlen(temp)-1;

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++) {
    ret[i] = temp[end];
    end--;
  }

  free(temp);
  return ret;
}
```

when I run this on my machine I get the following as output:

```
Binary to decimal: 11001
Octal to decimal: 157
Hexidecimal to decimal: ?8
```

Would someone be able to point out why when I do the hexadecimal conversion I get a question mark instead of a letter? Thank you!

Comment: What on earth is this: `temp[i] < 58`?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Also don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. I don't see you terminating your strings.

Answer (score 1):

This block is wrong:

```
    if(temp[i] < 58)
      temp[i] += '0';
    else
      temp[i] += 'a';
```

`58` is the ASCII code for the character after `9`. But `temp[i]` doesn't contain an ASCII code, it contains the numeric value of the digit -- you're converting it to character codes in this block. So you should be comparing with `10`.

And if it's at least 10, you need to subtract 10 when adding to `'a'`.

So the correct code should be:

```
    if(temp[i] < 10)
      temp[i] += '0';
    else
      temp[i] += 'a' - 10;
```

You didn't add a null terminator to `temp`, so you can't use `strlen()` to find its length. But you don't need to do that, because `i` contains the length of `temp`.

So you can change the second loop to:

```
int end = i-1;
for (i = 0; end >= 0; i++, end--) {
    ret[i] = temp[end];
}
ret[i] = '\0';
```

In `main()` you need to assign the return value of `decToBase()` to a variable so you can call `free()` after you've printed it.

```
char *binary = decToBase(2, 25);
printf("Binary to decimal: %s\n", binary);
free(binary);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a couple of similar base converting functions and I just lost track. Thank you for helping me out! :D

Comment: Don't forget to clean up your memory.  Your function allocates a string and returns it.  The caller is responsible for freeing that memory when it's no longer required.  Your program as currently written just leaks that memory.